# How to build Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I want to take a look on Fluent NHibernate but unfortunately I cannot find any information on how to build it from the sources. Maybe someone can help me? What tools I need for building it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Build.bat file only contains one command, and that is "rake" which is [Ruby Make](http://rake.rubyforge.org/). This runs rake in the current folder, using the file "rakefile" to build the project.

So, you need rake to be able to build using the bat file. If you are using Windows, you can install Ruby by using the [Ruby installer for Windows](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), which includes rake.

Answer (score 0):

I've already built it using VS, so the question is 'which tools I need to build it using the Build.bat file'