# Deletion of one-to-zero or one child record not working

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to map a couple of tables where the primary key in *Bar* is a foreign key to *Foo* i.e. a 1..0:1 relationship.

My mappings look like this:

```cs
class FooMapping : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
        Table("Foo");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");

        HasOne(x => x.Bar).Cascade.All();
    }
}

class BarMapping : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMapping()
    {
        Table("Bar");

        Id(x => x.FooId).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Foo");

        HasOne(x => x.Foo).Constrained();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to remove an instance of *Bar* by setting `Foo.Bar = null` and `Bar.Foo = null`, the record does not get deleted from the database.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it delete the reference from Foo to Bar (sets the column in the database to null)?

Comment: There is no reference to Bar in the Foo table. Like I said, the primary key in Bar is also a foreign key to Foo.

Answer (score 0):

So basicly the problem is that you're using `Cascade.All()` in the mapping of `Foo`.
Instead of that you should be using `Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()`.

**Cascade.All**

when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found.

**Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan**

when an object is save/update/delete, check the associations and save/update/delete all the objects found. In additional to that, when an object is removed from the association and not associated with another object (orphaned), also delete it.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there is no *Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan* defined on a *HasOne*.

Comment: @SimonMorgan looking at this: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1262 one-to-one relations should have it. Which version of NHibernate are you using?

Comment: @SimonMorgan also maybe this could help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867594/6870620

Comment: Although it appears NHibernate supports AllDeleteOrphan on one-to-one relationships, support hasn't been added to Fluent NHibernate. There's a pull request from 2017 but it's been ignored.

Comment: I've tried the mappings in the URL linked from that answer and I still have the same problems of records not getting deleted when i remove the relationship.

Comment: @SimonMorgan I'm sorry. It seems this isn't an issue of NHibernate but of FluentNHibernate... I've stumbled upon multiple pull requests on github adding the support for `AllDeleteOrphan` to the 1 to 1 relations...

Maybe you could somehow map this specific class via XML (not 100% sure if you can use both fluent and xml in the same project but i assume it works). 

Maybe you wanna download FluentNHibernate's source and do the change by urself. Then compile and include it into your project. Link to the PR: https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/pull/379

Comment: You're right. As I mentioned in another comment, I "fixed" the issue by modifying the Fluent NHibernate assembly to add support for `AllDeleteOrphan` on one-to-one relationships. Either way, thanks for your help.

Comment: @SimonMorgan Btw: It's merged by now and you should be able to use native nHibernate code again :)

Answer (score 0):

There is other dirty solution by making this relation with using HasMany and Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan.

```
class FooMapping : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMapping()
    {
       Table("Foo");
       Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
       HasMany(x => x.Bar).KeyColumn("FooId").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. I'm not sure where KeyColumn expects to find the "FooId" column but the foreign key that points to Foo is the primary key of Bar. Even when I seem to tell it the name of the key column, it errors because it's trying to initially set the value to null which isn't allowed because it's a primary key. Chaining .Not.Nullable() makes no difference.

Comment: You could try to using it with option Inverse(). The Bar instead of set null value of pk it should generate delete statement.

Comment: Still can't get it working. It's like it's trying to figure out the foreign key but getting it wrong (seems to think there's a "Foo_id" column involved somewhere) even though I have my ID set up properly on both sides of the relationship.

Comment: My last idea, maybe you could try override default name of generated Bar pk name e.g. Id(x => x.Food,"ColumnName").

Comment: Thanks but, like I say, I've already got the ID columns mapped correctly. I'm pretty certain that zero-to-one or zero relationships (that can be deleted) are impossible out-of-the-box using Fluent NHibernate. I hacked the assembly using dnSpy to add support for Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan and it works great without any hacks. Shame the Fluent NHibernate PR has been sitting on GitHub since 2017.

Comment: @SimonMorgan it's great that you hack this. Simon, so you add AllDeleteOrphan to CascadeExpression and it's ok ?

Comment: Yup. Here's [a link to the PR](https://github.com/FluentNHibernate/fluent-nhibernate/pull/379).